# Trigonometric equations: cotangent

Tags: trigonometry

If I have

$cot(x-a)=cot(x-b)$

Where x is in radians and equal on both the sides and not equal to $0$ or $π$ 
Also for a and b, they are not equal to $0$ or $π$

Does the above equality mean $a=b$?
If not then how do we even find the value of a and b?
Do we need any more conditions?

There are no singularity points of cotangent between points $(x-a)$ and $(x-b)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is $a=b$ ?

**Not necessarily**. Because $\cot$ is periodic with a period of $n\pi , n\in \Bbb Z$.

So, $\cot(x-a) = \cot(x-b) = \cot(n\pi+x-b) \implies \color{purple}{a =m\pi +b} , m =-n \in \Bbb Z$

Comment: sorry I missed to mention something. Can you check the answer for it again?

Comment: The condition that $\cot(\theta)$ is continuous between $\theta=x-a$ and $\theta=x-b$ rules out all the cases where $m\neq 0,$ so indeed $a=b.$

Comment: @David K what if I have $cot(λ(x-b))$  what you said above, does it hold true? Bcz if I have $λ[(x-a)-(x-b)]<π$ it would imply $b<(π/λ)+a$

Comment: If it's $\cot(\lambda(x-a))$ and $\cot(\lambda(x-b))$ then you have $\lambda a = m\pi + \lambda b.$ In that case the continuity condition implies that $\lvert \lambda(b-a)\rvert < \pi,$ so again you have $a=b.$

Comment: @David K sorry I don't get it. it is $<π$ why does it imply a=b? We can have $π/3$ in the interval for example.

Comment: If $\lambda = 3$ then indeed $a=b+\pi/3$ is a solution to $\cot(\lambda(x-a)) = \cot(\lambda(x-b)).$ But then the condition for continuity is not $\lvert b-a\rvert<\pi,$ it is $\lvert \lambda(b-a)\rvert<\pi.$ If $\lambda = 3$ and $a=b+\pi/3$ then $\lvert \lambda(b-a)\rvert = \lvert 3(b-(b+\pi/3))\rvert = \lvert -\pi\rvert = \pi.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97555/discussion-between-korra-and-david-k).

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use that $$\cot(x)-\cot(y)=-\csc (x) \csc (y) \sin (x-y)$$

Comment: ?? But I do t want for cot(x)-cot(y)@Dr. Sonnhard Graubner.   Thanks for the equation though, might be helpful someway

Comment: @Korra To make this hint a little more explicit, substitute $x-a$ for $x$ and $x-b$ for $y.$ Then the identity in this answer tells you that $\cot(x-a)-\cot(x-b)=-\csc(x-a)\csc(x-b)\sin(b-a).$ And you already know that $\cot(x-a)-\cot(x-b)=0.$ This tells you something about the right-hand side of the equation, especially $\sin(b-a).$

Comment: @David K yup! Got it $sin(b-a)=0    ==>    b-a=nπ$

Answer (score 1):

$\cot$ is a periodic function that repeats its value after ever $π$ interval i.e $\cot(X) = \cot (nπ + X)$.